# Access attribute via obj key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've simplified my work to this small example.

I am writting a library for a class "myClass" that has a few attributes ( user, name, weight, height ) and a list of targets ( = element id's ). The idea is that if I update my class all the data in the targets get updated.

Within my example you'll notice "test123". This is the part I do not yet know how to do. Which brings us to my question:

To dynamically update each target I've created an object ( see: this.classNames ) with all the class names and the attribute name as keys. If I have the key (ex: user) can I access this.user ? Is this even possible?

Here is a working jsfiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b1nj8064/3/)

**JS**

```
(function () {
    var myClass = function (o) {
        if (!(this instanceof myClass)) {
            return new myClass(o);
        }
        if (typeof o === 'undefined') {
            o = {};
        };

        this.user = o.user || 'unknown';
        this.name = o.name || 'unknown';
        this.weight = o.weight || 'unknown';
        this.height = o.height || 'unknown';

        //targets -- strings that start with #
        this.targets = [];

        this.classNames = {
            user: '.user',
            name: '.name',
            weight: '.weight',
            height: '.height'
        };

    };
    myClass.fn = myClass.prototype = {
        init: function () {}
    };
    //must start with #
    myClass.fn.addTarget = function (tar) {
        this.targets.push(tar);
        return this;
    };
    myClass.fn.update = function (o, callback) {
        if (typeof o === 'undefined') {
            o = {};
        }

        this.user = o.user || this.user;
        this.name = o.name || this.name;
        this.weight = o.weight || this.weight;
        this.height = o.height || this.height;

        var $this = this;

        //asynchronous update
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Here I loop through all the targets                
            $.each($this.targets, function (index, value) {

                console.log(index + ' ' + value);

                //Here I loop through all the classNames
                $.each($this.classNames, function (key, className) {
                    console.log(key + ' ' + className);
                    //I only want to replace text 
                    $(value).find(className).contents().filter(function () {
                        return (this.nodeType == 3);
                    //=== Problem Here=== With "key" how do I access attributes?
                    }).replaceWith('test123');

                });
            });
            if (!(typeof callback === 'undefined')) {
                callback();
            }
        }, 0);
    };

    //exporting lib
    window.myClass = myClass;
})();
myClass().addTarget('#target1').addTarget('#target2').update({
    user: 'Grimbode',
    name: 'Kevin'
}, function () {
    console.log('update has finished');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="target1">
    <div class="user">a</div>
    <div class="name">b</div>
    <div class="weight">c</div>
    <div class="height">d</div>
</div>
<div id="target2">
    <div class="user">e</div>
    <div class="name">f</div>
    <div class="weight">g</div>
    <div class="height">h</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is look up the property on `$this` that corresponds to `className` inside your async update loop on the `.replaceWith` line. If so, change

```
.replaceWith('test123");
```

to

```
.replaceWith($this[className.substring(1)]);
```

In JavaScript, you can access a property name either with dot notation and a property name literal (e.g., `obj.foo`), or with brackets notation and a property name *string* (e.g., `obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression.

In your code, `className` has a leading `.` on it (e.g., `".user"`), so we want to remove that (`.substring(1)`) to get the property name (e.g., `"user"`), and then use that in `[...]` to look up the property value.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1nj8064/4/)